# PHP - efficiency of foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, foreach

My navigation menu currently has two foreach loops; the first will display all parent navigation links and the second displays sub-navigation links.

I am looking for a way to change the second foreach loop to only loop through relevant sub-navigation items, instead of checking through *each* navigation for each parent item.

What would be the best way to go about this?

**CODE:**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <?php
    if($grabNav = $db->prepare("SELECT caption,url,visibility,id,class,parent_id FROM navigation ORDER BY parent_id ASC, order_id ASC"))
    {
        $grabNav->execute();
        $grabNav = $grabNav->fetchAll();
        foreach($grabNav as $nav)
        {
            $visibility = true;
            switch($nav['visibility'])
            {
                default:
                case 0: $visibility = false; break;
                case 1: $visibility = true; break;
                case 2: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = true; } else { $visibility = false; } break;
                case 3: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = false; } else { $visibility = true; } break;
            }
            if(!$visibility) { continue; }
            if($nav['parent_id'] != -1) { continue; }

            $class = $core->output($nav['class']);
            if($nav['id'] == PAGE_ID) { $class .= ' selected'; }
            echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><a href="'.$core->output($nav['url']).'">'.$core->output($nav['caption'],true).'</a><ul id="subNav">';
            foreach($grabNav as $sub)
            {
                if($sub['parent_id'] == $nav['id'])
                {
                    $visibility = true;
                    switch($sub['visibility'])
                    {
                        default:
                        case 0: $visibility = false; break;
                        case 1: $visibility = true; break;
                        case 2: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = true; } else { $visibility = false; } break;
                        case 3: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = false; } else { $visibility = true; } break;
                    }
                    if(!$visibility) { continue; }
                    $subClass = $core->output($sub['class']);
                    echo'<li class="'.$subClass.'"><a href="'.$core->output($sub['url']).'">'.$core->output($sub['caption'],true).'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            echo'</ul></li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Bing's answer is better solution, but in case you don't like to do it by sql you can also make new tree array, where the root is the parent elements, but on the next level - children. You'll do it on one pass before the visualization and after that another pass for visualization.
If it isn't clear - tell me and I'll show you sample code for pre-pass.

I hope the sample below will help :)

```
<?php
// SAMPLE DATA
$grabNav=array(
    0=>array('id'=>1,'parent_id'=>-1,'caption'=>'main-1'),
    1=>array('id'=>3,'parent_id'=>1,'caption'=>'sub 1-1'),
    2=>array('id'=>5,'parent_id'=>1,'caption'=>'sub 1-2'),
    3=>array('id'=>7,'parent_id'=>2,'caption'=>'sub 2-1'),
    4=>array('id'=>6,'parent_id'=>4,'caption'=>'sub 3-1'),
    5=>array('id'=>2,'parent_id'=>-1,'caption'=>'home-2'),
    6=>array('id'=>4,'parent_id'=>-1,'caption'=>'home-3'),
    7=>array('id'=>8,'parent_id'=>-1,'caption'=>'home-4'),
);

$new_array=array();
// PRE - PASS to organize the results in the new tree-array
foreach($grabNav as $nav){
    if($nav['parent_id']!=-1){ // children
        if(!isset($new_array[$nav['parent_id']])){
            $new_array[$nav['parent_id']]=array(
                'data'=>array(),
                'sub'=>array(),
            );
        }
        $new_array[$nav['parent_id']]['sub'][$nav['id']]=$nav;
    }
    else { // parent
        if(!isset($new_array[$nav['id']])){
            $new_array[$nav['id']]=array(
                'data'=>array(),
                'sub'=>array(),
            );
        }
        $new_array[$nav['id']]['data']=$nav;
    }
}
// VISUALIZATION
foreach($new_array as $root){
    echo $root['data']['caption']."<br/>"; 
    foreach($root['sub'] as $branch){
        echo "--- ".$branch['caption']."<br/>"; 
    }
}
?>
<pre><?= print_r($new_array) ?></pre>
```

Comment: Yeah some example could would be great, :)

Comment: OK, only first confirm please if I understood right - when parent_id = -1, then it is first - root level - Right?

Comment: That is correct :)
Anything greater than -1 is a sub-item of a corresponding parent.

Comment: Fantastic job! That makes a lot of sense to me and I have a good idea about going about my navigation list now. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

In your initial query `db->prepare("SELECT caption,url,visibility,id,class,parent_id FROM navigation ORDER BY parent_id ASC, order_id ASC"))` you could `JOIN` with the same table `ON navigation.parent_id=id`.

**You will need to enumerate your selected fields to avoid 'more than one found' SQL errors**, for example `SELECT orig.caption AS caption FROM navigation JOIN navigation ON parent_id=id`.  Notice the `orig.caption AS caption` bit!